# Titan Graph Database Modularity/Community Detection

Tags: titan, modularity, tinkerpop

Is anyone aware of an existing way to execute a modularity (community detection) algorithm on a Titan graph? I'm looking for something like Gephi's modularity feature which I believe uses https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/.

The Gephi Toolkit appears to provide an implementation of [this algorithm](http://gephi.org/docs/toolkit/org/gephi/statistics/plugin/Modularity.html), which could be an option. Has anyone experimented with loading a Titan graph using the Gephi Toolkit via the Blueprints plugin?

One requirement is that this all needs to happen automatically and in-place. Meaning, I cannot export the graph as another format or manually run modularity detection using something like the Gephi Desktop Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this just doesn't exist yet.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/modularity/aureliusgraphs/iS4Wj7XZjp8/TkFMyFDAclkJ

I ended up using the gephi toolkit and writing some REALLY ugly wrapper hacks to utilize the Modularity class with a TitanGraph.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the solution you found?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this doesn't exactly answer the question, but for Blueprints-enabled graphs like Titan, the best option for doing this type of analysis is through [Furnace](http://furnace.tinkerpop.com).  Though Furnace is still under development there is a clustering algorithm present as an example:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/furnace/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/furnace/algorithms/vertexcentric/programs/clustering/PeerPressureVertexProgram.java

Comment: Furnace is the right place for something like this. It doesn't have the modularity algorithm yet though.